# How to use Kubernetes DNS lookup for NGINX set_real_ip_from

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress

I've written a NGINX whitelister service inside my K8 cluster. Because everything entering the cluster goes through the load balancer, I had to whitelist the forwarded IP address instead of the source IP directly.

In testing, I hardcoded it like this in the NGINX config:

```
set_real_ip_from x.x.x.x;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

Where `x.x.x.x` was the IP of the load balancer.

This worked.

I can't hardcode the IP in the actual deployment, so I was hoping to use the `kube-dns` service, like I used for the `proxy_pass`:

```
resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
proxy_pass http://{service}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local:$server_port;
```

Which also works.

However, this DNS lookup doesn't seem to work for `set_real_ip_from`:

```
resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
set_real_ip_from {load balancer service}.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

When I run this, I just get `access forbidden by rule, client: x.x.x.x`(it's not in the whitelist), where `x.x.x.x` is the load balancer's IP. That kinda makes sense, since `set_real_ip_from` probably doesn't know to lookup the IP.

**Is it possible to have NGINX do a DNS lookup for the forwarder address?**

If not, maybe someone has a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach your yaml definision files e.g. of the load balancer service ? Is `kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local` resolvable from nginx pod ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just needed to sleep on this. Much simpler than I was making it.

I know the range that the load balancer should fall into, so I can just do a CIDR block for `set_real_ip_from`.

For example:

```
set_real_ip_from 10.60.0.0/16;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

And there is no need for a DNS lookup.